# Как очистить строку?

Tags: php

Парсю данные, и на выходе получаются вот такие строки

```
array:2 [▼
0 => """
Цена:\n
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t312 000 тнг
"""
1 => """
Цена:\n
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t7 847 тнг
"""
]
```

Как очистить эти строки и получить только цифры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать регулярное вырожение:

```
preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $string);
```

Это удалит все двойные пробелы, табы и новые линии.

```
preg_replace("/\D/", "", $string);
```

Это вернет только цифры.